# Max spans (500) for transaction has been reached

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

I getting this  error from APM server “WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.Span - Max spans (500) for transaction has been reached. For this transaction and possibly others, further spans will be dropped. See config param 'transaction_max_spans' “. Could anybody  please help on this?

I tried span_compression_enabled (elastic.apm.span_compression_enabled = true )in properties file in my java spring boot project  this go to be compressed spans will not be collected (Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/config-huge-traces.html#config-span-compression-enabled). I have added elastic.apm.version :1.32.0 dependency in pom.xml also.but  getting error for Cannot resolve configuration property 'elastic.apm.span_compression_enabled'

Comment: elastic.apm.span_compression_enabled = true  is s JAVA Property, not a spring boot property.  Adding it to your application.yml will not getting to work.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue ?